# Removing leading digits from string using Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I see many questions asking how to remove leading zeroes from a string, but I have not seen any that ask how to remove any and all leading digits from a string.

I have been experimenting with combinations of `lstrip`, `type` function, `isdigit`, slice notation and regex without yet finding a method.

Is there a simple way to do this?

For example:

- "123ABCDEF" should become "ABCDEF"
- "ABCDEF" should stay as "ABCDEF"
- "1A1" should become "A1"
- "12AB3456CD" should become "AB3456CD"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple way could be to denote all digits with [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.digits), which quite simply provides you with a string containing all digit characters `'0123456789'` to remove with [`string.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip).

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> s = '123dog12'
>>> s.lstrip(digits)
'dog12'
```

Answer (score 7):

I want to point out that though both Mitch and RebelWithoutAPulse's answer are correct, they do not do the same thing.

Mitch's answer left-strips any characters in the set '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'.

```
>>> from string import digits
>>> digits
'0123456789'
>>> '123dog12'.lstrip(digits)
'dog12'
```

RevelWithoutAPulse's answern on the other hand, left-strips any character known to be a digit.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('^\d+', '', '123dog12')
'dog12'
```

So what's the difference? Well, there are two differences:

- There are [many other digit characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) than the indo-arabic numerals.
- `lstrip` is ambiguous on RTL languages. Actually, it removes leading matching characters, which may be on the right side. Regexp's `^` operator is more straightforward about it.

Here are a few examples:

```
>>> '١٩٨٤فوبار٤٢'.lstrip(digits)
'١٩٨٤فوبار٤٢'
>>> re.sub('^\d+', '', '١٩٨٤فوبار٤٢')
'فوبار٤٢'

>>> 'foobar'.lstrip(digits)
'foobar'
>>> re.sub('^\d+', '', 'foobar')
'foobar'
```

(note for the Arabic example, Arabic being read from right to left, it is correct for the number on the right to be removed)

So… I guess the conclusion is be sure to pick the right solution depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is good to note, yes, if the limitations of my answer are not somewhat implicit at least :)

Answer (score 1):

Using regexes from [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
re.sub('^\d+', '', '1234AB456')
```

Becomes:

```
'AB456'
```

replaces any positive amount of digits at the beginning of the string with empty string.